# Using two while loop or single loop for different resultsets

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is what I have right now where, I am making multiple JDBC connections based on the IP address I have.

```
Map<String,Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();
DeviceStmt = connRemote.createStatement();
DeviceRS = DeviceStmt.executeQuery(maindbsql);

while (DeviceRS.next()) {
    try {
        final String ip_address = DeviceRS.getString("IP_vch");
        System.out.println("Value of IP_vch Field:"+ip_address);
        connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
        + ip_address + ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));

        if (connections.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Not successfull");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection to"+ip_address+"is successfull");
        }
    } catch(SQLException ex1) {
        System.out.println("While Loop Stack Trace Below:");
        ex1.printStackTrace();
    }
}//END Of while(DeviceRS.next())
```

What I want to have :
Say for example I am making connections to following IP's : 11.11.1.111 and 22.22.2.222

I want to excute an additional query on 11.11.1.111 just after connection is established after the following line in the above code:
`connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip_address + ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));`

Since, I can't use the same resultset(DeviceRS) which I have already used , I am wondering how can I run a different query.

I want to do something like the following:

```
DeviceStmttwo = connRemote.createStatement();
DeviceRStwo = DeviceStmttwo.executeQuery(maindbsqlnew);
```

below the following code I mentioned in the above code:

```
DeviceStmt = connRemote.createStatement();
DeviceRS = DeviceStmt.executeQuery(maindbsql);
```

Should I go for different while(DeviceRStwo.next()) option just before the existing while(DeviceRS.next()) loop and make connections again which seems to be a overhead to me.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's *really* hard to read in its current form.

Comment: You put the entry into HashMap and then check if it is empty. Think, how could it possibly be empty?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas What if I don't receive anything in `ip_address` in the following statement `final String ip_address = DeviceRS.getString("IP_vch");` ?

Comment: even the String is null, the map could not be empty, HashMap allows null key.

Comment: Hmm, so basically the check is of no use then.